# memset not filling array

Tags: c, memset

```
 u32 iterations = 5;
 u32* ecx = (u32*)malloc(sizeof(u32) * iterations);

 memset(ecx, 0xBAADF00D, sizeof(u32) * iterations);
 printf("%.8X\n", ecx[0]);

 ecx[0] = 0xBAADF00D;
 printf("%.8X\n", ecx[0]);

 free(ecx);
```

Very simply put, why is my output the following?

```
0D0D0D0D
BAADF00D
```

ps:
u32 is a simple typedef of unsigned int

edit:

- Compiling with gcc 4.3.4
- string.h is included

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The second parameter to memset is typed as an int but is [really an unsigned char](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/).  0xBAADF00D converted to an unsigned char (least significant byte) is 0x0D, so memset fills memory with 0x0D.

Comment: Oh, that is quite silly. What would be the best approach of going about filling it? Just looping over it manually, or is there a function designed for dealing with larger types than char?

Comment: @Daniel, it's *silly* because that routine uses the `stosb` assembly command to set the bytes very fast, but it doesn't support the `stosw` (word) & `stosd` (dword).

Comment: @Daniel: unless you measure it to be a performance bottleneck, writing a simple loop is the best way to go.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108866/is-there-memset-that-accepts-integers-larger-than-char

Comment: The reason that `memset` takes an `int` even though it really wants an `unsigned char` is that it dates from the days before ANSI C, when function prototypes were introduced.  Arguments to unprototyped functions are widened to `int` / `unsigned int`, so to make the prototyped ANSI C definition of `memset` compatible with the old unprototyped definition, it had to take `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to memset() is a char not a int or u32.  C automatically truncates the 0xBAADF00D int into a 0x0D char and sets each character in memory as requested.

Answer (score 2):

I tried it with wmemset(). It seems to work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void){
  uint32_t iterations = 5;
  uint32_t *ecx = (uint32_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t) * iterations);

  wmemset( (wchar_t*)ecx, 0xBAADF00D, sizeof(uint32_t) * iterations);
  printf("%.8X\n", ecx[0]);

  ecx[0] = 0xBAADF00D;
  printf("%.8X\n", ecx[0]);

  /* Update: filling the array with memcpy() */
  ecx[0] = 0x11223344;
  memcpy( ecx+1, ecx, sizeof(*ecx) * (iterations-1) );
  printf("memcpy:   %.8X %.8X %.8X %.8X %.8X\n",
             ecx[0], ecx[1], ecx[2], ecx[3], ecx[4] );
}
```

Comment: I think the reason you got downvoted is that wmemset takes a wide character argument (aka wchar_t), which is 16 bits, not 32.  But that's interesting: I never knew that function existed.  Neat.

Comment: what's the output?
0D0D0D0D? F00DF00D?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I thought that wmemset wasn't working for you, but it is :)

Comment: @sambowry: I guess it depends on the implementation.  It's based on an underlying integral type, so your compiler may have chosen int instead of short.  After googling a bit, it looks like wchar_t is typically 2 bytes on Windows and 4 bytes on Linux/Mac.  Since the asker is using gcc, it's probably Linux, so this would work for him.  Still, it's not really portable.  Nice solution.  +1

Answer (score 0):

The trick with `memcpy( ecx+1, ecx, ...` does not work here on Linux. Only 1 byte is copied instead of `iterations-1`.