# C++ memset() for long (64bit) types

Tags: c++, memset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there memset() that accepts integers larger than char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108866/is-there-memset-that-accepts-integers-larger-than-char)

As it can be seen in memset's declaration:

```
void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );
```

Is there any way to use this memset function (or another function included in STL library) so that you can set memory to a **long long** type value?

I use this to initialize an array of long longs with a large value.

I have to say that I've "solved" this problem by simply iterating through each value of the array and setting it to the desired value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108866/is-there-memset-that-accepts-integers-larger-than-char

Comment: Generally `memset()` is used to initialize the values of a block of memory to a fixed value (one byte at a time).  If you have a `long long` value you want to set, you can easily do that (safely is depending on HOW you do it) with casting (unless you have some unaligned access issues).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`memset` only uses one byte of the value passed in and does bytewise initialization. If you want to initialize a `long long` array with a particular value, just use `std::fill` or `std::fill_n` and let your library and compiler optimize it as they can (partial loop unrolling etc).

Another canonical C++ way is to just use `vector` and let its constructor do the work for you:

`std::vector<long long> foo(length_of_array, 12345678901234LL);`

Comment: +1 For the C++ way of filling an array.

Comment: If you want to initialize to a large value to use as "infinity" something like memset(ptr, 0x7f, size) should work. 0x7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7fLL is pretty big.

Answer (score 3):

Using memcpy seems slow to me, you have support for native 64 bit integers in your compiler, in this case this function should be more efficient using directly int64 if you are compiling in release mode.
However, consider that this function as it is written now supports only count as to be a multiple of 8.
If you need to work with any kind of number of bytes you need to deal with the little-endian big-endian problem.

```
inline void memset64(void* buffer, int64 value, size_t count)
{
    const size_t m = count / 8;
    int64* p = (int64*)buffer;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i, ++p)
        *p = value;
}
```

But we are on C++ right?
Let's use something more C++ oriented.

```
template <typename T>
inline void fillarray(T* buffer, const T& value, size_t count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        buffer[i] = value;
}
```

As noted in comments, there is also the function `std:fill`

Comment: In C++, one simply uses `std:fill`.

Answer (score 0):

memset only uses the lowest 8 bits of 'value' - it's meant to copy a single value to every memory location.  It doesn't try or attempt to deal with multi-byte values that might introduce issues with endianness etc.

If you want to fill memory with a long long value, I'd probably be curious as to why you want to do that -- there is probably a better way.

Comment: But memset seems to work on 4bytes int (multi-byte value) ... but seems to stop going any further

Comment: According to all docs I can find, that 2nd parameter is cast to an (unsigned char) regardless of what is passed in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `memcpy` function to do this. Assuming your long long type is 8 bytes, you can do something like:

```
long long mylonglong=...;
char memory[8];

// Copy the value of a long long into a character array
memcpy(memory,&mylonglong,8);
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to write the `long long` value to multiple consecutive locations in memory.