# Is there a memset alternative for more than one byte?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memcpy, memset

Is there a `memset` or `memcpy` operation to set a single int16, or int32 to an entire array?

Basically I have an integer array and I want to broadcast a single value to all of its elements.  `memset` only supports setting a 1-byte char.

Comment: [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) + compiler optimizations.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number thanks for the answer, (mind to post as answer?)

Comment: I think its not an answer, but just a comment. I mean its just a fancy way of saying "Write a loop and call it a day"

Comment: If you are dynamically allocating the memory you can also change to `std::vector<std::uint32_t> values(size,initial_value);`  [std::vector constructor 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).  Or you can use [std::array's fill method](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/fill)

Comment: It would help if you could show some of your current code that you want to change.

Comment: duplicates: [Can memset be used for multi-byte types and non-zero values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42578790/995714), [Initialization of all elements of an array to one default value in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1065774/995714), [C++ memset() for long (64bit) types (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7893217/995714)